# Is this possible at the c# event?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
using static main.main2;

namespace main;
class MainClass
{
    public delegate void dele();
    public static event dele? eve;

    private static void Main()
    {
        eve += a;
        if (eve != null) { eve(); }
    }
}
static class main2
{
    public static void a()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

I made an example to specifically ask the question.
If method a() is deleted from the above example, an error occurs in eve += a; this part.
I know why there is an error.
Is there a way to prevent errors without method a()?
Is there a way to add a to eve only when method a() exists?

Thank you for reading it. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what you are exactly trying to achieve. For instance, if you want to have different behavior in debug and release environments, you could if `#if DEBUG`, but if you want to build a plug-in system, you probably need a completely different solution like dependency injection and/or reflection

Comment: I'm sorry to ask you a vague question. What should I do if I want to build a plug-in system in that way? Is there any other place I can refer to?

Comment: _"Is there a way to add `a` to eve only when method `a()` exists?"_ - No, but you can subscribe with a delegate that executes `a()` by reflection, only if it exists like: `eve += CreateInvoker(typeName: "main.main2", methodName: "a")` where `CreateInvoker` creates a `dele` (an `Action` would be nicer though) that resolves the specified type, gets the `MethodInfo` and executes it if exists. Is this what you want?

Comment: Please as mentioned try improving the question and describing more of what you want in detail, this question is very vague and difficult to answer if we do not know the end goal.

Comment: For a plug-in architecture, you might want to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, You could use reflection to check whether method `a` is defined or not and based on it you can  call `eve += a;`

```
var methodInfo = typeof(main2).GetMethod("a", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
if (methodInfo != null)
{
    eve += main2.a;
}
```

Comment: It says `a` is not in the current context

Comment: which line? @Neo

Comment: @Neo I have assumed here that your code is compiling without error. I have fixed the error. but you should have mentioned in your question that you are getting a compilation error. check update answer

Comment: When I clear the method `a()`, `eve + = a;` in this part, `a` is not in the contest.

Comment: @viveknuna `main2.a` will still result in a compile error when the method `a()` from the class `main2` is missing.

Comment: @Progman I have compiled the code, it’s working fine for me

Comment: @viveknuna You can compile it when the method  `main2.a` exists, but you can't compile it when it is missing, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/pJePw8

Comment: @Progman oh sorry I just misunderstood the problem initiaylly. I can't delete my answer because it's already been accepted. Let me ask OP if he/she can unaccept my answer, I will delete it

Comment: @Neo please unaccept my answer, so that I can delete it